# Why will "0.0u 0.0s 0:00.00 0.0% 0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w" display on screen from cshell?

Tags: csh

friends, I don't know why "0.0u 0.0s 0:00.00 0.0% 0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w" (and many lines like this) will display when I run some C shell script, but not when some others run. And I never encountered with this problem before, which won't affect my results of my program. I think there are some problems in the following cshell command lines after I debugged.

```
set time = `saclst KZDATE f $file61 | awk '{print $2}'`
set yea61 = `echo "$time" | awk 'BEGIN {FS="/"} {print $1}'`
set mon61 = `echo "$time" | awk 'BEGIN {FS="/"} {print $2}'`
set day61 = `echo "$time" | awk 'BEGIN {FS="/"} {print $3}'`

set time = `saclst KZTIME f $file61 | awk '{print $2}'`
set hou61 = `echo "$time" | awk 'BEGIN {FS=":"} {print $1}'`
set min61 = `echo "$time" | awk 'BEGIN {FS=":"} {print $2}'`
set sec61 = `echo "$time" | awk 'BEGIN {FS=":"} {printf "%5.2f", $3}'`
```

And the standard output to terminal is like the following:

```
lenovo@lenovo-ThinkPad X1-Carbon-5th:-/Desktop/SP_test/temps$ csh pandamp.csh  
-----------------------------------------  
create SAC file list   DONE!  
-----------------------------------------
0.0u 0.0s 0:00.00 0.0% 0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w  
0.0u 0.0s 0:00.00 0.0% 0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w  
0.0u 0.0s 0:00.00 0.0% 0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w  
0.0u 0.0s 0:00.00 0.0% 0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w  
0.0u 0.0s 0:00.00 0.0% 0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w  
0.0u 0.0s 0:00.00 0.0% 0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w  
0.0u 0.0s 0:00.00 0.0% 0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w  
0.0u 0.0s 0:00.00 0.0% 0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w  
0.0u 0.0s 0:00.00 0.0% 0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w  
0.0u 0.0s 0:00.00 0.0% 0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w  
0.0u 0.0s 0:00.00 0.0% 0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w  
0.0u 0.0s 0:00.00 0.0% 0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w  
0.0u 0.0s 0:00.00 0.0% 0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
rotate from E, N and Z to R, I and Z 
-when you CAN see appropriate P and S marks:
Z component: a<f for P-up ; f<a for P-down ; a=f for P-bad 
-when you CAN'T see appropriate P and S marks: 
Z component: a<f for P-up ; f<a for P-down ; a=f for P-bad 
           & T9 before P; T8 before S 
R component: T9 before P; T8 before S 
T component: T9 before P; T8 before S
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0.0u 0.0s 0:00.00 0.0% 0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w  
0.0u 0.0s 0:00.00 0.0% 0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w  
0.0u 0.0s 0:00.00 0.0% 0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w  
0.0u 0.0s 0:00.00 0.0% 0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w  
0.0u 0.0s 0:00.00 0.0% 0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w  
0.0u 0.0s 0:00.00 0.0% 0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w   
0.0u 0.0s 0:00.00 0.0% 0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w  
0.0u 0.0s 0:00.00 0.0% 0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w  
0.0u 0.0s 0:00.00 0.0% 0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w  
0.0u 0.0s 0:00.00 0.0% 0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w  
0.0u 0.0s 0:00.00 0.0% 0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w  
0.0u 0.0s 0:00.00 0.0% 0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w  
0.0u 0.0s 0:00.00 0.0% 0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w
```

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997641/weird-thing-happens-in-a-simple-cshell-program

Comment: @Melebius, thank you for your good suggestion. I am a novice at Ask Ubuntu who am beginning to study Ubuntu system, and I am also not clear about the differences among each site of Stack Exchange. Now I have edited my question to improve my description, but I do not know how to do next for this question after you closed my question, editing to improve or deleting it because it is off-topic? Thanks!

Comment: Since you accepted the answer, no further action is needed. Your question could be reopened after your edit if the problem still existed but it was solved, wasn’t it? If your question can be solved using an answer from another SE site, then your question is a [duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/help/duplicates) (in a way) and therefore should remain closed, as are other duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to [this solution on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997641/weird-thing-happens-in-a-simple-cshell-program)

Essentially, it seems like an extra output from `set time = 00:01am` or similar.